# Server refusing public key with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, key-authentication

I am configuring our new RHEL 7 server and I am have a real pickle in trying to get it to accept my private/public keypair.

Everything seems similar enough compared to the sshd config from the older server.

Current `sshd_config`:

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile   .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem   sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Logging in using PuTTY I receive:

```
Using username "jweinraub".
Server refused our key
```

My permissions are

```
drwx------. jweinraub jweinraub unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 .ssh/
-rw-------. jweinraub jweinraub unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 authorized_keys
```

And with debug 3

`debug1: trying public key file /home/jweinraub/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug2: key not found
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7ff339f8afa0 is not allowed
Failed publickey for jweinraub from 10.18.66.11 port 55147 ssh2: RSA 1c:9d:1c:c7:cf:14:48:56:4f:23:5d:cb:16:a6:1d:18
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]`

Comment: What is the *content* of `authorized_keys`?  This looks like you have not placed a valid public key in `authorized_keys`.

Comment: `[jweinraub@nj-way-intranet:~/.ssh]$ cat authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAqtk9m3oUBFNb7lHPr0Z+MWHDg2E4ZdydjsgMpy7sqnLVpYkXv0SMaE+n0swSpbRT0791xE57NQFRiuUXN8+kabXC5zq3vcZd5QnP0qkrzunGYWn5OSuNBAto5Z9IG0PX3ihcV4g0YDlmzZlCtr1MKJ4UR5v90eL3UQwS7PJyu80VXVob/StDBAa/ZxKIYuxHhCjeExrhoSgVZOPMOUi2a2sRh2eHkV8EPBjtEOp0SIZYbB2ubUVln9v1HSWBSqYSPSOhUcHfo9/H1LW2POsNmMsjQay/E3nf+NP+Kf7zClUd1sxwhfDO8YT8lJ1wLaVrXkdwJgZ3UUl6Msk7zDERcQ== nj-way-intranet`   (the output from puttys keygen)

Comment: The key that you client offers is rejected (probably different key). Show us the public key prom puttygen and the reasl fingerprint (`ff:ff:...` stuff you mangled in the output).

Comment: I deobfuscated the above question, my fingerprint is `ssh-rsa 2048 eb:2e:2a:a5:b2:8b:22:be:2a:05:4c:e8:65:d8:d0:17`

Comment: Obviously that showed me it was wrong key, I deleted everything and redid it and now it works, honestly I had tried over and over numerous times, I must have been using the wrong private key from the public key I uploaded to the .ssh folder.  All is good again, thanks mate